# How can I re-use the same model template for different requests in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Imagine I have 20 charts on the index page of my application. I can request the data points for each chart in JSON:API form from the API:

```
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return {
            chart01: this.store.findAll('chart-timetable-01'),
            chart02: this.store.findAll('chart-timetable-02'),
            // ... etc
```

All routes from the API return a collection of documents that each represent a data point. Every document has the same attributes: `name` and `value`.

Now even though they are all exactly the same, I need to have 20 models:

```
models/chart-timetable-01.js
models/chart-timetable-02.js
# ... etc
```

Now that I want to introduce a second chart type with an actual different model, I want to simplify this. Can I use *one* model for all charts that are functionally the same, so that I don't have to duplicate the model for every new chart?

So in stead of `chart-timetable-{01..20}.js` I can have one simple `chart.js` model?

I can override the `type` with a serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data'

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {

        if (primaryModelClass.modelName.match(/^chart-timetable-/g)) {
            payload.data.forEach((doc, idx) => doc.type = 'chart')
        }

        return this._super(...arguments)
    }
})
```

But Ember still wants models named in the `findAll` to exist. How can I override this?

Comment: What is `{01..20}` in `chart-timetable-{01..20}`? They look like IDs of different charts to me. In that case you should switch from `store.findAll('chart-timetable-01')` to `store.findRecord('chart', '01')`. This would also allow you to use the same model for all charts.

Comment: You are correct. They are routes from the API. I know I would do it different if I had full control over the API code, but I don't. This question is about working around this problem on the Ember side of things.

Comment: I would recommend to work-a-round this API issue on Adapter / Serializer level. This would not only make your consuming code less complex but would also make it easier to drop the work-a-round as soon as your API was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get it correctly but maybe this will help.

Ember provides some helpful called rsvp. You can use it to store all data into return object

```
import { hash } from 'rsvp';
```

And then just place whatever You want:

```
return hash({
  chart01: this.store.findAll('chart-timetable-01'),
  chart02: this.store.findAll('chart-timetable-02'),
});
```

And now your model looks like:

```
chart01{...},
chart02{...}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. However, this (without `hash`) is already what I'm doing (see first code block). The problem that I am trying to solve is that for every `name` in `findAll(name)`, Ember expects a unique model file with that same name. I'm trying to find a way that prevents me from having to clone and maintain the exact same file 20 times.